# ZF 2 System configuration and config cache

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have some things that I can not understand.
It is **config_cache** from **system configuration**.

Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in subsequent requests.

```
'config_cache_enabled' => $booleanValue
```

Now i cant understand on waht configuration he thoughts.

- System Configuration

  or
- Application Configuration

  What configuration will be cached? System or Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would be an Application Configuration. Such files like Module.php and autoload/* would all be cached. However if you have any type of Closures in these files then you will not be able to cache these files as it will return an error (due to closures).

I personally have a few closures in my configurations so I need to do:

```
'config_cache_enabled' => false
```

Comment: Ok thanks for replay. So i test now and am not shure where system saving cache files. I configure **cache_dir** to data/cache but after few refresh data is empty. Its is posible to save in :memory: or ?

Comment: The only option for this type of cache is Filesystem. You wouldn't need anything more than that anyways for this. Make sure your data/cache folder is in the root folder and is writeable, IE (you could set it to 777 if you wanted)